# Viewport disable zoom and show all of the page

Tags: css, html, viewport

Hello I'm trying to make my website [www.ecogo.io](http://www.ecogo.io) to show the whole page instead of certain portion of it but it loads up on mobile browsers like Chrome Android zoomed in (both with Desktop mode on and off)

#### Here is a screen shot

[image]

The viewport I'm using is:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=900, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, shrink-to-fit=0">
```

Comment: Can’t reproduce, shows fine for me when emulating such devices using Chrome dev tools. // That this is not really user-friendly, should be obvious.

Answer (score 1):

change viewport from width=900 to width=device-width

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=900, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, shrink-to-fit=0">
```

to

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```